# Выполнение кода через каждые N шагов

Tags: php

Имеется цикл в `150` шагов. Требуется создать такое условие, при котором через каждые `50` шагов будет выполняться мой код. Ключевой вопрос в том, как выглядит такое условие.

```
$br = '<br />';

for ($i=0; $i<150; $i++) {

echo 'h';

if (требуемое условие)
  echo $br;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$i % 50 == 0
```

Остаток от деления на 50 равен 0. Т.е. число кратно 50ти.

Comment: `$i % 50 == 0` так у автора выведет после 51-ой записи `h`

Comment: В таком случае, нужно использовать `$i % 50 == 1` или начать отсчет с единицы. Суть не меняется.

Comment: тоже неверно выведет. Счет нужно начинать с единицы.

Answer (score 5):

```
$br = '<br />';

for ($i=1; $i<=150; $i++) { // $i = 1 чтобы счет начинался с 1, а не с 0

    echo 'h';

    if ($i % 50 == 0 )
        echo $br;

}
```

Comment: Спасибо добрые люди!

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( ($i>0) && (($i % 50) == 0) )
```

Comment: в вопросе от 0 до 149 (`$i<150`), поэтому, наверное, на 0 надо выполнить.